# Hibernate rollbacks

Tags: hibernate, transactions, rollback

If I do the following

session.getTransaction().rollback();

is it then ok/possible to start calling save/update/delete etc. on the same session object? Couldnt find the answer to this in the [Hibernate Session/Transaction API](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/), or in the Hibernate reference documentation.

Or do you recommend me to close that Session object, open a new Session and begin a new Transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say close the session and open a new one. Hibernate is not known for being forgiving about abuse of its sessions. It may hurt performance a bit, but it will probably prevent a bug down the road.

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible/adviceable from a database point of view, but writing atomic code is so much better for readibility. You may even reuse the structure of a template method to forget about the wirings around your transaction.